# phase portrait for ode no initial value

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to make a phase portrait for the ODE y''-4y'+y=0,
I know how to solve this ODE
But I don't know how to make a phase portrait out of it.
I've looked at something about parametricplot, but still don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: You start off by writing it as a system of first order equations and then use StreamPlot. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593458/convert-second-order-ode-to-first-order-system

Answer (score 2):

As porposed by Moo's comment the substitution `y'[t]==x[t]` leads to `x'[t]==4x[t]-y[t]`:

```
StreamPlot[{ 4 x-y,x},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

[image]

The ode seems to be unstable!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do any manual work or substitution to convert the second order ODE to two first order ODE's. You can let Mathematica do that using its `StateSpace` function which does the conversion for you. Less chance of making an error.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
ode = y''[x] - 4 y'[x] + y[x] == 0;
vars = {x, y};
ss = StateSpaceModel[{ode}, {{y'[x], 0}, {y[x], 0}}, {{u[x], 0}}, {y[x]}, x];
eqs = ss[[1, 1]] . vars
StreamPlot[eqs, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

One can use `Solve` to get the linear vector field and, optionally, its eigenbasis:

```
ode = {y''[x] - 4 y'[x] + y[x] == 0};
(* get Jacobian amat *)
subs = {y'[x] == p[x], y''[x] == p'[x]};
amat = {y'[x], p'[x]} /. 
   First@Solve[Join[ode, subs], {y'[x], p'[x]}, {y''[x]}];
(* optional *)
evecs = Last@CoefficientArrays[amat, {y[x], p[x]}] // N // 
   Eigenvectors;

(* plot *)
StreamPlot[
 amat,
 {y[x], -1, 1}, {p[x], -1, 1},
 (* optional *)
 StreamColorFunction -> None,
 StreamPoints -> {Join[
   Thread[{0.8 evecs, Red}], Thread[{-0.8 evecs, Red}], 
   {Automatic}]}]
```

[image]